# How to get rid of [''] when reading .csv files in python

Tags: python, csv

I am opening and reading one .csv file at a time from a folder and printing them out as follows:

```
ownerfiles = os.listdir(filepath)
for ownerfile in ownerfiles: 
if ownerfile.endswith(".csv"):
    eachfile = (filepath + ownerfile)    #loops over each file in ownerfiles
    with open (eachfile, 'r', encoding="UTF-8") as input_file:
        next(input_file)
        print(eachfile)
        for idx, line in enumerate(input_file.readlines()) :
            line = line.strip().split(",")
            print(line)
```

However, when I do `print(line)` the files are printing as follows:

`/Users/Sulz/Desktop/MSBA/Applied Data Analytics/Test_File/ownerfile_138.csv`
`['']`
`['2010-01-01 11:28:35', '16', '54', '59', '0000000040400', 'O.Coffee Hot Small', 'I', ' ', ' ', '14', '1', '0', '0.3241', '1.4900', '1.4900', '1.4900', '0.0000', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0.0000', '0.0000', '1', '44', '0', '0.00000000', '1', '0', '0', '0.0000', '0', '0', '', '0', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'NULL', '0', 'NULL', '', '0', '20436', '1', '0', '0', '1']`

How can I get rid of `['']` before the list of all the data ??

**EDIT:**
I now tried reading it with the .csv module like this:

```
ownerfiles = os.listdir(filepath) 
for ownerfile in ownerfiles: 
  if ownerfile.endswith(".csv"): 
    eachfile = (filepath + ownerfile)     #loops over each file in ownerfiles 
    with open (eachfile, 'r', encoding="UTF-8") as input_file: 
      next(input_file) 
      reader = csv.reader(input_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='|') 
      for row in reader : 
        print(row)
```

However, it still prints output like this:

> [] ['2010-01-01 11:28:35', '16', '54', '59', '0000000040400', 'O.Coffee Hot Small', 'I', ' ', ' ', '14', '1', '0', '0.3241', '1.4900', '1.4900', '1.4900', '0.0000', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0.0000', '0.0000', '1', '44', '0', '0.00000000', '1', '0', '0', '0.0000', '0', '0', '', '0', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'NULL', '0', 'NULL', '', '0', '20436', '1', '0', '0', '1']

Comment: Sorry I was unclear on what I was asking! I actually meant how can I get rid of that little empty list `['']` that is listed before the output of the actual data?

Comment: You should use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) module in the standard library to read CSV files

Comment: well it depends on the data in your document, can you please add example of data that is in your document.

Comment: Guessing, it looks like you might have blank lines in your data files: `''.split(',') -> ['']`

Comment: I now tried reading it with the .csv module like this:
`ownerfiles = os.listdir(filepath)

for ownerfile in ownerfiles: 
    if ownerfile.endswith(".csv"):
        eachfile = (filepath + ownerfile)    #loops over each file in ownerfiles
        with open (eachfile, 'r', encoding="UTF-8") as input_file:
            next(input_file)
            reader = csv.reader(input_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
            
            for row in reader :
                print(row)`

Comment: However, it still prints output like this:
`[]
['2010-01-01 11:28:35', '16', '54', '59', '0000000040400', 'O.Coffee Hot Small', 'I', ' ', ' ', '14', '1', '0', '0.3241', '1.4900', '1.4900', '1.4900', '0.0000', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0.0000', '0.0000', '1', '44', '0', '0.00000000', '1', '0', '0', '0.0000', '0', '0', '', '0', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'NULL', '0', 'NULL', '', '0', '20436', '1', '0', '0', '1']`

Comment: That empty list is still in there at the beginning and I don't know how to get rid of it. I tried 
`row = [x for x in row if x != []]`

Comment: You should add that code to the question. It's unreadable here in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

That's just Python's list syntax being printed. You are splitting each line on a comma which is generating a list. If you print the line before the split you'll probably get what you're looking for:

```
line = line.strip()
print(line)
line = line.split(",")
```

By the way, Python has a [built in CSV module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) for reading and writing csv files, in case you didn't know.

**EDIT:** Sorry, I misread your question. Add this to the start of your readlines loop:

```
line = line.strip()

if not line:
  continue
```